# Powershell REG QUERY is not returning value as 0 or 1 however in microsoft page it is mentioned if success then return value as 0 else 1

Tags: cmd

REG QUERY 'HKLM\Software\policies\Microsoft\Windows NT' /f DCOM /k

I need the result in Success or Failure(0 or 1).

In the below link it is mentioned if success then return value as 0 else 1.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028(v=ws.11).aspx

But I am not getting the specified result.

How can we get the desired output.

Comment: *"... I am not getting the specified result"* What are you getting?

Comment: I am getting result "End of search: 0 match(es) found.", But I am expecting "1". as written in mentioned link of microsoft.......Please go through the mentioned link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired exit status is stored inside the `errorlevel` environment variable. You can test it by reading its value

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\policies\Microsoft\Windows NT" /f DCOM /k
echo %errorlevel%
```

Or you can use the native `if errorlevel` command to check

```
    reg query "HKLM\Software\policies\Microsoft\Windows NT" /f DCOM /k
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo FAILED
    ) else ( 
        echo OK
    )
```

note: remember that `if errorlevel n` will be evaluated as true for any `errorlevel` value greater than or equal to `n`, so checks should be made from greater to lower values.

**Edit**: I must be blind to not see the `powershell`.

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\policies\Microsoft\Windows NT" /f DCOM /k
echo $LastExitCode
```

Or, in cases as this where you will only test for sucess/failure, you can use `$?`

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\policies\Microsoft\Windows NT" /f DCOM /k
echo $?
```

In this case you will not retrieve a `0/1` value but a `True/False` value

Comment: reg query "HKLM\Software\policies\Microsoft\Windows NT" /f DCOM /k
echo %errorlevel%.......I am executing above command on windows powershell but not getting any result.

Comment: @Sharfi, I completly missed the *powershell* ... in the title !!!. I just saw the `reg` command and set my mind to `cmd` mode. My fault. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you , This is what exactly I was looking. I really appreciate your help.